# monetdb remote table: cannot register

Tags: monetdb

I have two nodes and am attempting to create a remote table.  To set up I do the following:

on each host:

```
$ monetdbd create /opt/mdbdata/dbfarm
$ monetdbd set listenaddr=0.0.0.0 /opt/mdbdata/dbfarm
$ monetdbd start /opt/mdbdata/dbfarm
```

On the first host:

```
$ monetdb create w0
$ monetdb release w0
```

On second:

```
$ monetdb create mst
$ monetdb release mst
$ mclient -u monetdb -d mst
password:
Welcome to mclient, the MonetDB/SQL interactive terminal (Dec2016-SP4)
Database: MonetDB v11.25.21 (Dec2016-SP4), 'mapi:monetdb://nkcdev11:50000/mst'
Type \q to quit, \? for a list of available commands
auto commit mode: on
sql>create table usr ( id integer not null, name text not null );
operation successful (0.895ms)
sql>insert into usr values(1,'abc'),(2,'def');
2 affected rows (0.845ms)
sql>select * from usr;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+======+======+
|    1 | abc  |
|    2 | def  |
+------+------+
2 tuples (0.652ms)
sql>
```

On first:

```
$ mclient -u monetdb -d w0
password:
Welcome to mclient, the MonetDB/SQL interactive terminal (Dec2016-SP4)
Database: MonetDB v11.25.21 (Dec2016-SP4), 'mapi:monetdb://nkcdev10:50000/w0'
Type \q to quit, \? for a list of available commands
auto commit mode: on
sql>create remote table usr_rmt ( id integer not null, name text not null ) on 'mapi:monetdb://nkcdev11:50000/mst';
operation successful (1.222ms)
sql>select * from usr_rmt;
(mapi:monetdb://monetdb@nkcdev11/mst) Cannot register  
project (
table(sys.usr_rmt) [ usr_rmt.id NOT NULL, usr_rmt.name NOT NULL ] COUNT 
) [ usr_rmt.id NOT NULL, usr_rmt.name NOT NULL ] REMOTE mapi:monetdb://nkcdev11:50000/mst
sql>
$
$ monetdb discover
             location
mapi:monetdb://nkcdev10:50000/w0
mapi:monetdb://nkcdev11:50000/mst
```

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

[EDIT - Solved]

The problem was self-inflicted, the remote table name must be exactly the same as the local table name, I had usr_rmt as the remote table name.

Answer (score 0):

at first sight what you are trying to do ought to work.

Recently, I had similar problems with remote table access, though that was with the non-released version, see [bug 6289](https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6289).  (The MonetDB version number mentioned in that bug report is incorrect.)  What you are experiencing may or may not be the same underlying issue.

After the weekend I will check if I can reproduce your example on, on -SP4 and on the development version.

Joeri